Sci-fi/fantasy trilogy set in the desert with 2 separate protagonists?
I remember reading a book trilogy as maybe a 11-13 year old. The first book follows a young woman travelling across a harsh desert. She had.some sort of magical power that connected her to the land, which was almost like Australia. I can’t remember whether it was an Australian author or not. She was travelling across the land to reach a certain place, which had a large wall, and the top of the wall led to another city I believe?
the second book in the series jumped to a different protagonist; this time a young man, living in a city suspended above the clouds which was the same city at the top of the wall. He found the girl and they were different as the people who lived in the ground were less educated and savage than the people in the cloud city. They couldn’t communicate to each other very well because of a language barrier? I’m not too sure what happened in the end of the second book.

The third book was both of them working together for some reason but I really can’t remember much about this book.

When were you 11 to 13?

Same story as being looked for in this reddit post? There's a few suggestions there (unless it's also your question XD): https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/13mr1co/scifi_trilogy_set_in_the_desert_with_a_dash_of/

Gonna leave this as a comment rather than an answer, but I wonder if this is Doris Lessing's The Marriages Between Zones Three, Four, and Five?

Please register your account so that you can edit your post with details.
